# Wordpress RSS Feed display raw shortcode (do not render)

Tags: php, wordpress, feed

I'm using the default RSS feed to pass some content through to some subsites I manage. But there are some shortcodes which are being rendered, but should be rendered by the subsites.

So how do I prevent the shortcodes from being parsed?

The shortcode it's about is from a plugin.

`[wb-rekentool "username/othername"]`

Comment: Can you include code examples?

Comment: You dont want to render any short code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! Used the "the_content_feed" filter to remove the shortcode:

```
function remove_sc_feed($content){
    remove_shortcode('wb-rekentool');
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'remove_sc_feed');
```

Easy, but the answer was nowhere to be found!